# Pattern / methodology for communication between Windows and/or UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, user-controls

I'm currently developing a application where I will have multiple windows open using C# and WPF.

Is there a pattern or common methodology used to help faciliate communication between open Windows or/and UserControls?

For example, a window, let's call it the 'Hierarchy Window', may displays a hierarchy of countries, provinces, and cities in the world. Outside of that there are several other Windows which may display a province or city for example **OR** allow you to create a province or city. In the case of creating a new city, which is the best way for my 'City Window' to communicate with my 'Hierarachy Window' regarding adding a city or removing a city?

Keeping in mind that the 'Hierarchy Window' might not even be open when a City is created. At which point, there is no need for a response/action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two common approaches to this:

1. Use Dependency Injection to inject a common service.
2. Use a messenger of some form.

The second option is becoming very popular with WPF and Silverlight.  Many common toolkits, such as [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) (for details, see the [Messenger class description](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/09/27/mvvm-light-toolkit-messenger-v2-beta.aspx)), use this approach.

Comment: I checked out the MVVM Light and while although it isn't the direction I am going to go, comments on the website lead me to the PRISM framework and event aggregator. Thanks for the tip! A messenger pattern will do very well in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to what Reed wrote above:

When I have implemented this (in my case using MVVM) I have tended to go for a Messenger/Mediator pattern first to get things up and running and then refactor it to use Dependency Injection.

For a good example of the Mediator pattern have a look at Sasha Barbers MVVM framework called [Cinch (on V2 now I think).](http://sachabarber.net/) You can download all the souce code and have a look at how he used the Mediator - its a very very good example. You can also have a look at the Microsoft Dev Lab project on [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) for .NET which implement IObservable's and IObserver - not directly related to your question but a very cool way to do messaging.

For Dependency Injection have a look at the [Microsoft Unity Application Bloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203101.aspx)k stuff

Hope that helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out the [PRISM](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) framework (in WinForms this used to be CAB - Composite Application Block). It's a part of the Microsoft Patterns & Practices.
 You can use event publication and subscription to communicate between objects in a very easy and straightforward way:

```
//publish:
 eventAggregator.GetEvent<ItemAddedEvent>().Publish(MyItem);

//subscribe:
eventAggregator.GetEvent<ItemAddedEvent>().Subscribe(MyMethod);
```

I haven't used it thoroughly enough yet, but they provide a whole lot of documentation and a whole sleek of features to support DI, Commands and Validation. Worth to check out!

Answer (score 0):

To me, this sounds like you need to implement the Model-View-Presenter Pattern. See [MVP on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647117.aspx).